# Angular Redirect inside Observable subscribe

Tags: angular, redirect, rxjs

I use Angular 4 for a custom component to upload audio only on one page (it's not SPA). When file has uploaded I want to redirect browser to page `http://website/profile/tracks`.

My service call looks like:

```
this.uploadService.uploadTrack(this.trackForm, csrfToken).subscribe(res => {
  this.redirectToTracks();
  this.loading = false;
}, err => {
  this.loading = false;
});
```

upload service:

```
uploadTrack(track, csrfToken): Observable<any> {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Csrf-Token', csrfToken);
  return this.http.post('/profile/upload', track,  {headers: headers});
}
```

and redirect function:

```
redirectToTracks() {
  window.location.href = '/profile/tracks';
}
```

But it's not working, it seems like Angular calls it like a background request:

[image]

If I put console.log(res) in subscribe it logs redirection there

But if I put redirect just in ngOnInit() it works fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is to use NgZone:

```
constructor(private utilsService: UtilsService,
              private uploadService: UploadService,
              private zone: NgZone,
              ){ ... }

this.uploadService.uploadTrack(this.trackForm, csrfToken).subscribe(
    res => {
      this.loading = false;
      this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        window.location.href = '/profile/tracks';
      });
    }, 
    err => {
      this.loading = false;
    });
);
```